# Treeview events with Attached Command Behavior

Tags: wpf, treeview, attachedbehaviors

I want to handle events on a treeview with ACB (http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/attachedcommandbehavior-aka-acb/).

I am stuck with the bindings in the XAML file. The event is fired but I keep getting null reference exceptions in the ACB library because strategy is null:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the strategy
    /// </summary>
    public void Execute()
    {
        strategy.Execute(CommandParameter);
    }
```

In the XAML file I added the following (excerpt):

```
xmlns:acb="clr-namespace:AttachedCommandBehavior;assembly=AttachedCommandBehavior"

    <StackPanel x:Name="VerklaringenTreeviewPanel">
    <Border x:Name="TreeviewHeaderBorder" Style="{StaticResource TreeviewBorderHeaderStyle}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbTreeviewHeader" Text="Verklaringen concept" Style="{StaticResource TreeviewHeaderStyle}"/>
    </Border>

    <TreeView x:Name="MyTreeview" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource TreeviewStyle}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="..\Themes\TreeviewItemStyle.xaml" />
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>

    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyDataType}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyChildDataType}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" acb:CommandBehavior.Event="MouseDown" acb:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" acb:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter="Hi There">
```

And in the Viewmodel I added:

```
        Public Property SomeCommand() As ICommand
        Get
            Return _someCommand
        End Get
        Private Set(value As ICommand)
            _someCommand = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        Dim simpleCommand As SimpleCommand = New SimpleCommand()
        simpleCommand.ExecuteDelegate = Sub(x As Object)
                                            Dim test As String
                                            test= "noot" 'I want to hit this breakpoint
                                        End Sub
        Me.SomeCommand = simpleCommand
    End Sub
```

Who can help me out with the binding?

Regards,

Michel

Comment: There is your SomeCommand property is defined? On MyDataType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The not too descriptive exception is throw because this binding is broken: `acb:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"`.

So WPF could not find your `SomeCommand` property. I guess the problem is around the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` so the `DataContext`is not what you would expect...

Check for binding errors in the Visual Studio's Output window during runtime and you will know what to fix then it should work.

Comment: Now, that's handy! I didn't now that the output window shows binding errors.  

*System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SomeCommand' property not found on 'object' ''MyDataType' (HashCode=47761)'. BindingExpression:Path=SomeCommand; DataItem='MyDataType' (HashCode=47761); target element is 'StackPanel' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')*

Comment: Now the question is: where is your `SomeCommand` defined because from the error not on `MyDataType` which is the current `DataContext`. If you fix it then the `acb:CommandBehavior` should work.

Comment: I am missing something, I would like to have the command on the viewmodel instead of my businessentity. How can I target the VM?

Comment: Without seeing the big picture: how the viewmodel and businessentities are realted where do you set the `DataContext`s etc. it's hard to tell... please update the original or create a new question...

Comment: DataContext is the ViewModel, however the treeviews DataContext is member ViewModel.MyDataType. So the question now is how to get to the VM with the datacontext set to a member.

Comment: YES! *{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.SomeCommand}*. Voted for your binding errors and datacontext hints!